# Scientific notation literal with variable exponent in Python

Tags: python, scientific-notation

The literal `3e4` represents the `float` 30000 in python (3.8 at least).

```
>>> print(3e4)
30000.0
```

The syntax of the following code is clearly invalid:

```
x=4
3ex
```

`3ex` is not a valid expression, but the example helps me ask my question:

Clearly, the expression `3*10**4` represents the same number, but my question here is purely related to the scientific notation literals. Just for my curiosity, is there a way to use the same syntax with a variable power, better than:

```
x=4
eval(f"1e{x}")
```

One subtle difference between `3e4` and `3*10**4` is the type (float and int respectively).
Is there also a difference in execution time perhaps in calculating these two expressions?

Comment: Here's link to [float](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c), looking now for something about `3e4` syntax ... I think [float_from_string_inner](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L165) calls [PyOS_string_to_double(s, (char **)&end, NULL)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/conversion.html#c.PyOS_string_to_double)

Comment: "Is there also a difference in execution time perhaps" is an easy quesiton to answer for yourself using the timeit module, great for testing execution times of various versions of your code

Comment: I think this is source for [PyOS_string_to_double](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L337)

Answer (score 3):

To your **first question**: No, the documentation does not suggest you can.

> *Is there a way to use the same syntax with a variable power?*

When float is [instantiated from a string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L165), it calls out to a CPython C library [PyOS_string_to_double](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L337) to which handles making the str locale-aware (`.` vs `,`) before passing the string directly to the C function `strtod` [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/).

Meanwhile the [documentation for PyOS_string_to_double](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/conversion.html#c.PyOS_string_to_double) does not mention of any special way to configure the exponent.

To your **second question** about performance, this is easily benchmarked.  But, we do not have a candidate to benchmark against.  So, this is a moot question.

> Is there also a difference in execution time perhaps?

I hope this satiates your curiosity.  If not, feel free to dig into the C code that I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's clear now. I did not know that `3e4` was a string and needed a string conversion, I thought it was directly parsed as float.
the performance I wanted to compare was the one of calculating the expression `3*10**4` against the expression `3e4`. I admin I do not know how the latter is calculated, hence the question. I'll dig into the code, thank you!

Comment: @MarcoP Ah and now I see where you are coming from that the `3` and `4` might be direct-value instantiators into the *mantissa* and *exponent* of a float!

Comment: yes exactly, I was wandering about how the scientific notation literal works